# Android SimpleDateFormat and future dates

Tags: android, date

```
long time = 1342580400; //This should be GMT: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 03:00:00 GMT
Date date = new Date(time);
SimpleDateFormat dateSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
String strTime = dateSdf.format(date);
System.out.println(strTime); //This gives me 16 Jan instead.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the following code:

```
  SimpleDateFormat dateSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z");
  Date d = dateSdf.parse("18 Jul 2012 03:00:00 GMT");
  System.out.println(d.getTime());
```

You will get the output: `1342580400000`

So your problem is that you are missing a few numbers.

Comment: `missing a few numbers` means that `new Date()` takes milliseconds and you provided seconds...

Comment: @WarrenFaith, you are right. I didn't realize the OP missed exactly a factor 1000

Comment: Thanks can't believe I missed that, my tired eyes.

Comment: Was a PHP thing with time returning epoch time in milliseconds and having to calculate yourself. This is the solution for PHP 5 taken from another post function msTimeStamp() {
    return round(microtime(true) * 1000);
}

Answer (score 1):

```
 Date dt = new Date();

            // Fri Dec 02 17:23:13 GMT+05:30 2011

            DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
            TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
            gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
            gmtFormat.format(dt);
            Calendar new_c = gmtFormat.getCalendar();

            int hours = new_c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minutes = new_c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int seconds = new_c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            mYear = new_c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            MMonth = new_c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = new_c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            new_c.setTimeZone(tz);

            MMonth = MMonth + 1;

            String curdate = mDay + "-" + MMonth + "-" + mYear;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your manual calculation of date from time is wrong. I tried the following code :

```
long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Date date = new Date(currTime);
    SimpleDateFormat dateSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
    String strTime = dateSdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(strTime);
```

And it gave me the correct date viz 21 Dec